# Pusher client stuck on reconnecting mode

Tags: android, laravel, kotlin, websocket, pusher

I've been trying to connect to my laravel server using a pusher client for a while now and without success. When I try to connect to pusher's servers the connection is successful. With my server on the other hand the results are mixed.

When I leave encryption set to true I get the following exception: 
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`
Which I'm assuming is due to the server's certificate not being signed by a trusted authority.
so, I set encryption to false what I get are the following logs:

```
10-29 10:37:23.991 23048-23658/xxx connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:37:24.041 23048-23658/xxx connection state changed RECONNECTING
10-29 10:37:25.041 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:37:25.081 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed RECONNECTING
10-29 10:37:29.081 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:37:29.141 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed RECONNECTING
10-29 10:37:38.151 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:37:38.221 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed RECONNECTING
10-29 10:37:54.231 23048-23658/xxxx E/teste: connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:37:54.301 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed RECONNECTING
10-29 10:38:19.301 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:38:19.371 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed RECONNECTING
10-29 10:38:49.371 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed CONNECTING
10-29 10:38:49.441 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed DISCONNECTING
10-29 10:38:49.441 23048-23658/xxx E/teste: connection state changed DISCONNECTED
```

It never connects.

```
        val pusherOptions = PusherOptions()
        pusherOptions.setHost("aaa.bbb.ccc")
        pusherOptions.setWssPort(xxx)
        pusherOptions.setWsPort(xxx)
        pusherOptions.isEncrypted = false
        pusherOptions.pongTimeout = 300000

        pusher = Pusher("appkey", pusherOptions)

        pusher?.connect(object : com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener{
            override fun onConnectionStateChange(change: ConnectionStateChange?) {
                Log.e("teste","connection state changed ${change?.currentState}")

            }

            override fun onError(message: String?, code: String?, e: Exception?) {
                Log.e("teste","error : $message")
                Log.e("teste","exception: ${e.toString()}")
            }

        },ConnectionState.ALL)
```

Comment: Digging deeper into the pusher client library: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java I managed to log what happens between connecting and reconnecting. The code I get is -1 the reason field is empty and the remote flag is set to true.